# Как получить статистику загрузки ЦП за промежуток времени в linux?

Tags: linux

Есть мнение, что одна из установленных и запущенных программ кушает ЦП.

Могу я как-то посмотреть статистику по этой программе, к примеру за последний час?

В привычных мне top и htop, как я понял, показывается только статистика в реальном времени, а это мне не подходит.

Comment: Atop крутится в фоне и собирает статистику. Ещё можно собирать своим скриптом данные из /proc сколько процесорного времени съела программа и затем посчитать сколько это от общей утилизации cpu

Answer (score 2):

Так например можно каждую секунду запускать команду `ps` для определенного `pid` с выводом в файл `stats.txt`. Можно разные вариации и баловаться с форматом вывода, записывая ещё например текущее время или другие параметры. Потом можно построить график в каком-нибудь `gnumeric`

`watch -n 1 'ps -p <pid> -o %cpu | tail -1 >> stats.txt'`